# How to access collection of source directories of all included build in composite build of Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build-tools

I have a gradle project with composite build. I have to get the source files collection to use in jacoco instrumentation. Is there any to get the source directories of all included builds.

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'my-composite'

includeBuild 'my-app'
includeBuild 'my-utils'
```

I am currently using files method to get the collection in build.gradle

```
project.ext.files1 = 
fileTree("C:/my-composite/my-app/src").matching {
    include '*.java'
}

project.ext.files2 = 
fileTree("C:/my-composite/my-utils/src").matching {
    include '*.java'
}

project.ext.allFiles = project.ext.files1.plus(project.ext.files2)
```

can we generate the source list dynamically using **gradle.includedBuild('my-app')**?
(or)
Is there any way to use a task to return source directory of each inculdede build?
or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do:

```
fileTree(gradle.includedBuild("my-app").projectDir.resolve("src")).matching {
    include("*.java")
}
```

Comment: it does not work if the source folder name is different. is there any way to use a task to return source directory of each inculded build.

Comment: Not that I could see...  The object returned by `includedBuild` doesn't have sourceSets :-(